# ElasticSearch aggregation counting query

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have got the following document:

```
"_index": String,
"_type": String,
"_id": String,
"_source": {
    "id": String
    "sendDate": Date
    "title": String
    "author": String
    "language": String
    "keywords": Array<String>
}
```

I would like list and count every single keyword from whole type from database. Have you maybe any tips for me?

Comment: I created sth like below
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "item": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keyWords","size": 1000000
      }
    },
    "total_terms": {
  "cardinality": {
      "field": "keyWords"
  }
}
  }
}

but it shows only single words, sometimes keyword is built from a few words

Comment: it would be great if you edit your question and add the result you get and the result you expect.

Comment: @TarasKohut Sure, i ll post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer

```
{
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "item": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "keyWords.raw",
            "size": 1000000
          }
        },
        "total_terms": {
          "cardinality": {
                "field": "keyWords.raw"
          }
        }
      }
}
```